# How do I recreate this photo filter/edit similar to Instagram's Walden filter in Photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, software-filters

I'm trying to recreate on old filter in Photoshop that used to be available on an app called Facebook Camera but the app hasn't been updated in years and no longer runs on iPhone.

Original:
[image]

Edited:
[image]

It's similar to the Walden filter used on Instagram but it's more blue, darker but still retains warmth.

I'd love if anyone has any tips about recreating this in Photoshop as I'm not really sure where to start! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can get close, but I'm retaining too much detail overall. Curves, haze/clarity, vignette & split-tone so far, but really need to get the haze right, will look again tomorrow when I've more time & try provide a fuller answer.
Trouble with Camera RAW is you can't jump back in to see your settings if you change your mind, it always starts over:\

<sup>click for full size</sup>
Camera RAW settings

[image]

My quick edit,  OP's version & original for quicker comparison

[image][image][image]

Comment: Ah thank you @Tetsujin. I know that part of the filter includes a vignette that makes the centre part of the image lighter which doesn’t help figuring out the correct colours. Looking forward to see what else you can achieve tomorrow!

Comment: tbh, I've now tried this in 3 different apps. In each I can get "close but no cigar". In Photoshop I could at least snapshot the parameters, in Aurora & Luminar you can't display them all at one time, so even if I got it in one of those, it would be tough to show precisely how. I've pushed the PShop one baack through some more clarity/haze just to see if it would get any closer, but tbh I push one parameter & 5 others need to be tweaked to compensate. One step forward, two steps back.